# How to manipulate individual median points in edit mode?

Tags: mesh

Let's say I have some faces on the same plane that are part of a larger object and I only want to scale their individual median points outwards *without deforming them*. How do I achieve that? I noticed that there is the option "manipulate center points" but unfortunately that only exists in object mode.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from your rather unclear question, what you are looking for is the pivot point menu.
Select individual origins after selecting your faces, then you will be able to scale the faces around their center pivot point.

Like this:

**Select Individual Origins**

[image: PivotPointMenu]

**Using the default Median Point method**
*(scales around the net center of all selected faces)*

[image: MedianPoint]

**Using the Individual Origins method**
*(scales around the individual faces origins)*

[image: IndividualOrigins]

If this is not what you were looking for, please let me know.

Comment: Close but not exactly. Each face has a median point and all these different faces' median points have another main median point. If you use the first method then the faces will grow larger as well. That's what I don't want. I only wanna scale the distances from the main median point.

Comment: It is complex if you wanna get a perfect looking result easily and/or have lots of them to move. The closest I have gotten is to move/scale them using the first method by typing the factor x and then scale them down using the second method with factor 1/x. I just use it quite often and I was wondering if there's a more straightforward way that will also enable me to use the mouse instead of typing factors.